# What is the correct workflow in GIT to update branchA which previously merged in branchB

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I created `branchA` (my branch) and then merged `branchB` into it (someone else's branch):

```
checkout branchA
merge branchB
```

Commits were made on `branchB`, and I modified one local file in `branchA`.

I want to pull in the recent changes from `branchB` to `branchA`.

I ran `git fetch origin` under the assumption that I was updating the local copies of `branchA`, `branchB`, and `master` (the 3 branches I have locally). I saw new commits in both `branchB` and `master` when I ran `git fetch origin`.

I then tried `git merge branchB`, but I run into merge conflicts in files I don't maintain or touch.

I'm clearly not understanding the correct workflow here, can someone point me to the correct process?

Update:

If I run `git pull origin branchB` I get the same merge conflicts.

Comment: Have a look with gitk first and check which changes have been made to both branches since your merge.
Btw: did you commit the merge?
In doubt post the first few lines from git log for analysis.

Comment: In the commit log I have a commit with the default description `Merge branch branchB into branchA`. So I think I have commited the merge. I have one commit in `branchA` after that. I'll look into `gitk` I haven't heard of that.

Comment: Conflicts can occur when you are using `git merge` while your team members are using `git rebase`. If this issue bothers many in your team, you can decide either one of `git merge` or `git rebase` as a best practice for the team.

Comment: You may want to read about [git rerere](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere)